# Update stock in Magento 2 by SKU on another site via API from one site

Tags: php

I am trying to update stock in Magento 2 by SKU on another site via API from one site.

It works on my machine (localhost), but it's not working on the server.

I don't know why, can you please look at my code.

**Here is my PHP Code:**

```
public function setStock($sku = '',$stock = 0){
    $_catalogProductURL = 'https://www.atomicgolf.shop/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token/';
    $adminUrl = self::$_catalogProductURL;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $data = array("username" => "admin5", "password" => "admin55555");

    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init($adminUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    $token = curl_exec($ch);
    $token = json_decode($token);

    //Use above token into header
    $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $token","Content-Type: application/json");

    $skus = array(
        $sku => $stock
    );

    foreach ($skus as $_sku => $_stock) {
        //$requestUrl='https://www.atomicgolf.shop/index.php/rest/V1/products/' . $_sku . '/stockItems/1';
        $requestUrl='https://www.atomicgolf.shop/index.php/rest/V1/products/' . $_sku . '/stockItems/1';

        $sampleProductData = array(
            "qty" => $_stock,
            "is_in_stock" => ($_stock > 0 ? true : false)
        );
        $productData = json_encode(array('stockItem' => $sampleProductData));

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $requestUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $productData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump($response);

        unset($productData);
        unset($sampleProductData);
    }
}
```

Comment: it work in localhost with magento 2.1.7 but not work in magento 2.1.5 on hosting. it can update stock (qty) in it's database. I use from one site to update another site.

Answer (score 0):

This code can work on both localhost and hosting. If It will have problem, it can be cause from magento htaccess.

Comment: Please check your .htaccess in first root directory.